# WebException on first run: NotFound

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

When I execute the following code on the dispatcher thread, my windows phone app throws WebException exception each time I start to debug with a fresh emulator:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Moo);
}

private async void Moo()
{
    await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.de");
}
```

Strange enough, it only occurs when there was no emulator instance before and it had to go through the boot process. As long as I press VS' "restart debug" button, I repeatedly get the same error, but if I stop debugging and then start again without closing the emulator, it works just fine.

The Exception itself is pretty much meaningless: The response stream is empty and it terminated with NotFound, while the Status was UnknownError. Stack trace (of the inner web exception):

```
at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
```

Source was System.Windows. Let me know if you need any more info.

How can make it work for the first emulator runs? Where should I look for the error? Certainly not in connectivity of the windows phone I think.

Comment: Have you tried with a real device? Maybe the problem is only reproducible on the simulator which,by the way has,some disturbing limitations.

Comment: I just tried the first time and it works out of the box.

Comment: And just a side note: `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` returns `true` in all cases.

Comment: That's right. The documentation says that the emulator is always connected to a 3G network and connected to a battery charger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a real device as this could be one of the several limitations the emulator has (for example the emulator is always connected to a 3G network and connected to a power charger).